# @InjectMocks causes NPE

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following `ApplicationConfiguration`:

```
class ApplicationConfiguration {
    private SQSConfig SQSConfig;
    // Other configs and getters/setters
}
```

Then I have in my `Application`

```
class Application {
   private Dequeuer dequeuer;

   public void run(ApplicationConfiguration config) {
       // I need to pass ApplicationConfiguration because there are other variables that I need to use
      dequeuer = new Dequeuer(config);
      // Start dequeuer
   }
}
```

So in my test for `Application`, I want to use `@InjectMethod` for the `Dequeuer`:

```
class ApplicationTest {
    @Mock
    private ApplicationConfig config;
    @Mock
    private SQSConfig sqsConfig;
    @InjectMocks
    private Dequeuer dequeuer = new Dequeuer(config);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(config.getSQSConfig()).thenReturn(sqsConfig);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `@InjectMethod` is initialized before the `when`, so I get a NPE. What do I do?

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't compile. Post **real** code.

Comment: @JBNizet the real code would be long. The point of this question is how to use `@InjectMethod` if you need to have more of a mock than a simple `MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class)` and you need to use `when` to setup your mock.

Comment: I'm not asking for your real code. I'm asking for real code that reproduces the problem, and makes sense. You're using classes that don't exist, `new Dequeuer(ApplicationConfiguration)` is not valid Java code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is, the @InjectMethod is initialized before the when, so I
>   get a NPE. What do I do?

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` will indeed first create mocks, and this is the way which it should work. You don't record a mock behavior before instantiating a mock.

Besides, it is not `@InjectMock` but `@InjectMocks`.

And you don't use it correctly.

Don't pass the parameter to the constructor, it will be directly injected by the Mockito framework if your `Dequeuer` class declares a `Dequeuer(ApplicationConfig appConfig)` constructor:

```
@Mock
private ApplicationConfig config;
...
@InjectMocks
private Dequeuer dequeuer;
```

The NPE is probably caused by a bad use of the Mockito Framework but with the code shown in your question, this is hard to identify.

Comment: I did that, but @InjectMocks is still called before the `when` in my `setUp`. I confirmed that by putting `System.out.println` at different stages of the `Application`, `Dequeuer`, and the test file. So I get an error saying `You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null`

Comment: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` will indeed create mocks first, and this is the way which it should work. You don't record a mock behavior before instantiating a mock.